# Typescript Omit with key and value comparison

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a type from two interfaces by omitting all keys of the intersection from the first given interface, but only if the key + type match, so that two interfaces like this:

```
interface Car {
  wheels: number;
  doors: number;
  driver: number;
}

interface OtherTypeOfCar {
  wheels: number;  // type match
  doors: string;   // string here BUT number in Car
  windows: string; // not in Car
}

type OmitWithTypeMatch<A, B> = // to be implemented

type ResultingCar = OmitWithTypeMatch<Car, OtherTypeOfCar>;
```

would result in:

```
const car1: ResultingCar = {
  doors: 5,  // number
  driver: 1, // number
}; // Car without wheels
```

However, when using Omit, I would get:

```
type ResultingCar = Omit<Car, keyof OtherTypeOfCar>;

const car2: ResultingCar = {
  driver: 1,
};

// wheels and doors get removed
```

Which is the behaviour I **don't** want.

Comment: does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gKGcgdwAsIIAbAZwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuPZAEwHtuprajFlHb5OUYADdoNeszY4AvjhyhIsRCgDyYElAAqATwAOELTHSZc+YqUqyhbZAHpnyMCZQM4YBEQ48fAIUYBIgAOasLm4hYeHIeigAQgCq+oLymKBoGEoqHqbIWgzAYACSMACiAB6QIJwUADz6AHzIALz46RC1EPUU2IQk5AJwIIbIisgA-PjFpc0ANMgA5LYjK200+jgF2iVgAIJkZBU1dQ1LyADSbZ3I3b39NzNzB1cA1hCG3DA3Ww98p4HhAQh1But7MgxhNlDgENwQGDOABGZBUeblKpPS6WO6DFaBfgrGho5biKQyZBoqbIFQIpFgLgAJnRmLOOKaOj0RlM5jx4KwqyJFBJq1Fk3piORAGY2QdjqdsRcubpoLyzBYMMt9KCwPihYTeMSaCsJYogA) works for you  ? (edited)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't, when doing OmitAllIfExtends<Car, OtherTypeOfCar> the resulting type should contain "doors" and "driver" but not "wheels"

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WGVLKm) meet your needs?  There are undoubtedly edge cases so please test against your actual needs and let me know if it works or not.  If it does, I'll write up an answer.  If not, please [edit] the question with an example where it goes awry.